# AudioKit: Virtual MIDI port confusion?

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm fiddling around with creation of virtual MIDI ports in AudioKit (v5-main).

It seems to me that there is a confusion on INPUT and OUTPUT ports, but then again, perhaps I'm not understanding what's going on.

I create Virtual MIDI Input and Output ports by:

```
let midi = MIDI()

midi.createVirtualInputPorts(numberOfPort: 1, [Int32(1000000)], names: ["MIDI Test Input Port"])
midi.createVirtualOutputPorts(numberOfPort: 1, [Int32(2000000)], names: ["MIDI Test Output Port"])
```

I do realise that I can do this in one go (createVirtualPorts), but I wanted control over the portIDs for further investigation.

But when I list my INPUT ports by displaying:

```
midi.inputUIDs
```

The OUTPUT (portID 2000000) shows up on the list.
And vice versa, if I use:

```
midi.destinationUIDs
```

... I see the INPUT (PortID 1000000).

To me, it would make sense if my virtual Input Port showed up on the Input (inputUIDs) list, and the Output port showed up on the Output (destinationUIDs) list. But it's the other way round.

Further investigating my problem, I tried to inspect the receivedMIDINoteOn to see the portID reported.

The port UID for incoming MIDI events is the OUTPUT (PortID 2000000).

I double checked to see how physical MIDI ports behave, and indeed, I receive MIDI notes on INPUT ports, as expected.

Am I missing something with regards to terminology here (Input/Output/Destination)?

Comment: Yes, the names seem to be swapped. It also appears backwards on external MIDI monitoring apps. In MIDI+VirtualPorts.swift, `createVirtualInputPorts` calls `MIDIDestinationCreateWithBlock`, and `createVirtualOutputPorts` calls `MIDISourceCreate`. Maybe there's a reason for it...

Comment: @Eggsalad. Ah, I didn't get to check that. Yes, you might very well be right. Not sure how I report this?

Comment: Not sure if this is intended or not. There's not much documentation on v5 yet. The AK devs monitor Stack Overflow periodically, which they say is the preferred way to raise issues, so I'd give it a couple days. You can also post at https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not even sure if this is isolated to V5, or if v4 also had the issue. Yeah, let's see, Aurelius often has very nice feedback here at Stack Overflow.